# Django: SQL queries on ManyToMany relationships

Tags: python, sql, django, phpmyadmin

I have an Application model that can take any number of Themes:

```
class Application(models.Model):
     themes = models.ManyToManyField(Theme)
     date_check = models.BooleanField(blank=True)
     # other fields...

class Theme(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     # other fields...
```

I need to deliver an exported database (via phpMyAdmin) containing only the Applications that have at least one theme (as well as some other filters). In Django, this is easy (although I'm sure what I wrote below is not the easiest way):

```
apps = Application.objects.filter(date_check=True)
filtered_apps = []
for a in apps:
    if len(a.get_themes()) >= 1:     # get_themes() returns a comma-separated list of themes
        filtered_apps.append(a)
```

I just don't know how to translate `a.date_check=True and len(a.get_themes()) > 1` into SQL, which I can run in phpMyAdmin to export an Excel file of the database. Any ideas?

**Edit:** I have solved the problem by using Django to directly export to Excel, rather than going through phpMyAdmin. For some strange reason I thought it would be more difficult via Django. I will leave this question up, though, because although my task is solved, this question is still not answered.

Comment: Why do you need "get_themes"? Just len(a.themes) should suffice.

Comment: `len(a.themes)` is really inefficient as it will convert the queryset into a list and then will count the elements. Is much better to count with `a.themes.count()` which does a SQL count. Much more efficient.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But what about doing this in SQL?